# Understanding of Execution plan in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl235.jpg)

I ran a SQL query in Oracle and generated this execution plan. I am new to Oracle execution plans. It will be great help if someone could please help me to under below execution plan generated in Oracle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl235.jpg)

Also what is mean by Predicate Information (Highlighted in Red)?

Query detail (what could be done to improve performance?)

```
select 
    master.acname,branch.bname,
    branch.blocation||'-'||branch.barea as blocation, 
    trans.location  as location,
    location.shortcode||'/'||substr(voucherno,1,8)||'-'||vouchertype||substr(voucherno,9,15) as voucherno,
    transtype.transtype,
    voucherdate, particular, trans.drcr,
    case drcr 
       when 'D' then amount 
       else NULL 
    end as debit,
    case drcr 
       when 'C' then amount 
       else NULL 
    end as credit,
    master.acname as repeatedname,
    master.accode as accode
from  
    trans, branch, master, transtype, location
where 
    trans.cid = 'BCDTRA0003'
    --and   trans.location=v_location
    and voucherdate between '01-APR-2015' and '01-APR-2015'
    and trans.accode in (select accode from master)
    and trans.deleteinvoice is NULL
    and trans.MANUAL = 1 
    and trans.voucherprefix = transtype.type
    and (master.cid = trans.cid or master.cid = '9999999999')
    and trans.accode = master.accode
    and trans.cid = branch.cid
    and trans.bid = branch.bid
    and branch.blocation = location.blocation
/
```

Comment: [Reading EXPLAIN PLAN output](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF94683).

Comment: Post the query and the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks Axiac for visiting my post. I have just place screen shot of execution plan and the used Query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the EXPLAINPLAN statement of Oracle.. here is the official documentation for this on Oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231